# C macro variable MQOD_DEFAULT fails to compile with gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, ibm-mq

I'm trying to use several structures from the C API of MQ-Series in c++ classes. Here's IBM's documentation of one of the structures https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/fr13840_.htm 
The problem appears to be the macro variables for example MQOD_DEFAULT. When initializing a structure globally (outside any function or methode) the initialization works. However inside a function or methode I get errors like:

```
    no match for >>operator=<< operand types are >>MQOD {aka tagMQOD&)}<< and >>brace-enclosed initializer list><<)
```

Globally compiles fine with gcc 4.8:

```
    MQOD od = {  MQOD_DEFAULT };
```

Inside a methode throws compile error no match for operator=...:

```
    void MyClass::Methode()
    {
      MQOD od = {  MQOD_DEFAULT };
    }
```

MQOD_DEFAULT is described by IBM as macro variable:

```
    #define MQOD_DEFAULT {MQOD_STRUCT_ID_ARRAY},\
                          MQOD_VERSION_1,\
                          MQOT_Q,\
                          {""},\
                          ...
                          ...
```

I found some more information in IBM's developer documentation (page 77) : ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/docs/V7.5/PDFs/wmq75.develop.pdf

To initialize the fields in such structures, the following technique is recommended:
         1. Declare an instance of the structure using the appropriate MQxxx_DEFAULT macro variable to
initialize the structure. This instance becomes the model for other instances:

```
MQMD ModelMsgDesc = {MQMD_DEFAULT};                                                               
/* declare model instance */
```

Code the static or auto keywords on the declaration to give the model instance static or dynamic
         lifetime, as required.
2. Use the calloc or malloc functions to obtain storage for a dynamic instance of the structure:

```
   PMQMD   InstancePtr;                                                                                
   InstancePtr = malloc(sizeof(MQMD));                                                               
         /* get storage for dynamic instance */
```

3. Use the memcpy function to copy the model instance to the dynamic instance:

```
    memcpy(InstancePtr,&ModelMsgDesc,sizeof(MQMD));                                                   
         /* initialize dynamic instance */
```

But InstancePtr = malloc(sizeof(MQMD)); gives me the same error "no operator="

What is the best way to resolve this ?

Comment: Initialization (`type x = value;`) is different from assignment (`x = value;`). The reference to `operator=` says that you are trying to assign a *"brace-enclosed initializer list"*. Just doesn't work.

Comment: Are you programming in C++ or C? Please don't use both tags - they're quite different.

Comment: as stated I'm programming in c++ but using IBM's MQ C API. I think it's crossing borders that's why. But I see your point. I'll remove the C tag.

Comment: @BoPersson ok, but why the different behavoiur ? Why don't I get that error when initialized globally ? respectively why do I get it when initializing within a function or methode ?

Comment: `operator=` is not involved in an initialization, so you are probably not doing what you think you are doing. If you had shown some of the code...

Answer (score 0):

```
MQOD od = {  MQMD_DEFAULT };
```

Wow. You went side ways - I guess slipper when wet!

First off, MQOD_DEFAULT, MQMD_DEFAULT, MQGMO_DEFAULT, MQPMO_DEFAULT, etc. are defines.  i.e. Simple C short-cuts to save a programmer from retyping things over & over again.

Secondly, you cannot (and should not) be using a define meant for one structure and use it for another structure.

```
MQOD od = {  MQOD_DEFAULT };
```

or

```
MQMD od = {  MQMD_DEFAULT };
```

but NEVER

```
MQOD od = {  MQMD_DEFAULT };
```

Third, I use "sizeof(MQMD)" all the time.

```
memcpy(InstancePtr,&ModelMsgDesc,sizeof(MQMD));
```

is the same as doing:

```
memcpy(InstancePtr,&ModelMsgDesc,sizeof(ModelMsgDesc));
```

Finally, I don't believe the error you are receiving is from the line you claim.

Comment: thank you for your input highly appreciated. MQMD_DEFAULT was actually a typo here. In the programm it was correct. I must have had too little sleep on this one. I will post an answer below to show what I actually wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I wanted to achieve. The IBM documentation on this is sparse and there are no examples to find. Maybe it's obvious to many but I think that I would have saved myself a lot of time had IBM provided a simmilar example in their documentation:

```
     #include <cmqc.h>

     #define NULL 0

     class MyClass
     {

       public:
         void use_MQCSP();

       private:
         MQCSP init_MQCSP();
         MQCSP mqcsp;
     };

     MQCSP MyClass::init_MQCSP()
     {
       MQCSP mqcsp_o = { MQCSP_DEFAULT };
       return mqcsp_o;
     }

     void MyClass::use_MQCSP()
     {
       mqcsp = init_MQCSP();
       mqcsp.AuthenticationType = MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD;
     }

     int main(int argc, char **argv)
     {

        MyClass mcl;
        mcl.use_MQCSP();

        return 0;
     }
```

compilation with gcc:

```
g++ pcftest.cpp -o pcftest -I /opt/mqm/inc/ -L /opt/mqm/lib64/ -lmqic
```

Compilation with Sun CC:

```
CC pcftest.cpp -o pcftest -I /opt/mqm/inc/ -L /opt/mqm/lib64/ -lmqic
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your MyClass question relates to your original question.  And I'm not a big fan of mixing procedural and object-oriented languages.  Why don't you pick one and then write your program using it?

Here's a C++ MQ program that I wrote.  It will connect to a queue manager using MQCONNX and MQCSP and then put a message from a queue.

```
/*
 * Program Name
 *  MQTest31.cpp
 *
 * Description
 * Test program to connect to a queue manager using MQCONNX and MQCSP
 * and then put a message from a queue.
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *   QMgrName ChlName hostname(port) QName
 *
 * Where
 *    QMgrName is the queue manager name
 *    ChlName is the name of the channel to be used
 *    hostname(port) is the hostname and port number
 *    QName is the queue name
 * i.e.
 *    MQTest31.exe MQWT1 MY.TEST.EXIT 127.0.0.1(1415) TEST.Q1
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix, Capitalware Inc.
 */

 /*
  * Standard Include files
  */
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <imqi.hpp>    /* MQI */

/*
 * mainline
 */
int main ( int argc, char * * argv )
{
   /* --------------------------------------------
    * Variable declarations.
    * --------------------------------------------
    */
   ImqQueueManager  mgr;
   ImqChannel      *pchannel = 0 ;
   ImqQueue         queue;
   ImqMessage       msg;
   /* */
   char     buffer[10240];
   char     myUserId[33]   = "tester";
   char     myPassword[33] = "mypwd";
   char     testMsg[] = "This is a simple test message.";

   /* --------------------------------------------
    * Code section
    * --------------------------------------------
    */
   if (argc != 5)
   {
     cout << "Usage: MQTest31 QMgrName ChlName hostname(port) QName" <<endl;
     return( 1 );
   }

   cout << "MQTest31 Starting." <<endl;

   // Create object descriptor for subject queue
   mgr.setName( argv[ 1 ] );

   pchannel = new ImqChannel ;
   pchannel -> setHeartBeatInterval( 1 );
   pchannel -> setTransportType( MQXPT_TCP );
   pchannel -> setChannelName( argv[ 2 ] );
   pchannel -> setConnectionName( argv[ 3 ] );

   mgr.setChannelReference( pchannel );

   queue.setName( argv[ 4 ] );

   /*
    * Specify UserId and Password via MQCSP
    */
   mgr.setAuthenticationType(MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD);
   mgr.setUserId( myUserId );
   mgr.setPassword( myPassword );

   /*
    * Connect to queue manager
    */
   if ( ! mgr.connect( ) )
   {
     cout << "MQTest31: connect CC=" << mgr.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << mgr.reasonCode() <<endl;
     return( 1 );
   }

   /* setup queue info */
   queue.setConnectionReference( mgr );
   queue.setOpenOptions(MQOO_OUTPUT + MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
   queue.open( );
   cout << "MQTest31: open CC=" << queue.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << queue.reasonCode() <<endl;

   if ( queue.completionCode( ) == MQCC_OK )
   {
      msg.useEmptyBuffer( buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
      msg.setMessageId( );
      msg.setCorrelationId( );
      msg.setFormat( MQFMT_STRING );      /* character string format    */
      strcpy(buffer,  testMsg);
      msg.setMessageLength( (int)strlen( testMsg ) );

      queue.put(msg);
      cout << "MQTest31: put CC=" << queue.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << queue.reasonCode() <<endl;
   }

   /* Close the queue */
   queue.close( );
   cout << "MQTest31: close CC=" << queue.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << queue.reasonCode() <<endl;

   /* Disconnect from the queue manager */
   mgr.disconnect( );
   cout << "MQTest31: disconnect CC=" << mgr.completionCode()<< " : RC=" << mgr.reasonCode() <<endl;

   /* clean up */
   if ( pchannel )
   {
      mgr.setChannelReference( );
      delete pchannel ;
   }

   cout << "MQTest31 Ending." <<endl;
   return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: I was not really precise with my question because I didn't fully understand the problem at the time. Basically I program in c++ but IBM's c++ support is a bit weak. For example, I couldn't find support for pcf in the c++ API. That's why I wrap around the C API... much like I guess xms does.